# PortAudio low latency setup Mac OS X

Tags: macos, audio, portaudio, low-latency

I'm learning how to use PortAudio and so far it seems like a pretty straight forward Library to implement in a project.

Thing is I'm trying to figure out how to get a really low latency I/O stream going in my Mac OS X program. I know there is a specific header file (pa_mac_core.h) included for the Mac platform to do specific things but the documentation seems a little fuzzy to me.

Ultimately I'm trying to get <10ms latency using a thunderbolt audio interface I have at my disposal.Any help would be appreciated!